# Begin captain in FIFA 17 in player career mode

Tags: fifa-17

I just finished the sixth season in the same club where I was elected the best player every year and I have exceeded the seasonal goals. I expected to become a captain, but didn't.

How can I become a captain of my team?

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Start over with a smaller team